# How to share text from android app to facebook?

Tags: java, android

I try to implement share button in my android app to share in facebook
The code:

```
facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,desc.getText().toString());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share description using"));


            }
        });
```

The problem is, in the post dialog of the facebook not display the text which i need to share from my app which it is (desc.getText().toString()) . There empty message !! why the text didn't appear !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot share only text on facebook by using share intent, you must have to use some link also. you can check this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share text via Intent on Facebook without using Facebook sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618514/share-text-via-intent-on-facebook-without-using-facebook-sdk)

Comment: share link !!! do you mean link of my application ?

Comment: This code maybe help you! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36910262/2996974)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Hope it help

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share Something");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```